How virtual nodes affects consistent hashing ring?
Given the consistent hashing ring system, i.e., with $S$ serves, $C$ clients and a random hash function $h$, how can we choose the number of virtual nodes per server $V$, so that the probability that there exists a server with a bottelneck (i.e., more than $p\cdot C$ clients are associated with it) will be very low (with probability of at most $1/N$ for a large $N$)?
I tried to use look at the analysis of the original articles of consistent hashing (i.e., https://publications.csail.mit.edu/lcs/pubs/pdf/MIT-LCS-TR-716.pdf and https://www.cs.princeton.edu/courses/archive/fall09/cos518/papers/chash.pdf)  but it was very complicated and generlized for me to understand it. Especially, when they assume a $k$-wise independent hash family, which for my particular purposes results in very high upper bounds.
Also, a similiar question was asked here, How are virtual nodes placed / calculated to implement consistent hashing without no formal solution.
When I tried to approach the problem, I use the following formulation:

Denote $X^{v}_{s}$ as the number of clients allocated to server $s$ of its $v$ virtual node.
Denote $X_{s}= \sum_{v\in V} X^{v}_{s}$ the the number of clients allocated to server $s$.
Use the balls in bins Poisson approximation, i.e., $X^{v}_{s} \sim P(\frac{C}{V\cdot S})$  and $X_{s} \sim P(\frac{C}{S})$, all RV are independent one from another. This is based on https://www.cs.dartmouth.edu/~deepc/LecNotes/Rand/lec11+12.pdf, Theorem 4, as we deal with monotone events.
Use tail bounds on $X^{v}_{s}$ and  $X_{s}$.

The problem with this approach, is that the number of virtual nodes do not affect here the tail bounds. This means, since the sum of independent RV Poisson is a Poisson RV by itself, we don't have any gain by using the virtual nodes.
What am I missing? Can I get better bounds which depends on the number of virtual nodes? and if so, what it the maximum effect of them, if any?
